# How to create a modal window using jquery and javascript to help a user make a choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create a modal window that contains a list of checkboxes. A user can select a checkbox (or several checkboxes). Depending on a user choise, a  section(s) next to the list must appear or disappear OR change its opacity and ZOOM.

An example of what I need is below:
http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/ - here you can click the blue button in the sidebar (what product is right for me?)

Here is also similar example (but not exactly what I need) http://www.kaspersky.com/help-me-choose

So, I can create a modal in the way like this:
(if there are betters ways to do this, please tell me)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.showmodal').on('click', function () {
            $('.modal').fadeIn(1000);
        });
        $('.hidemodal').on('click', function () {
            $('.modal').fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then I can create a list of check boxes:

```
<div class="modal">
    <div>
        <b>What do you want to do?</b><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="a1" checked>Question 1<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="a2">Question 2<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I can creale a number of DIVs next to the checkboxes list and using jquery change its opacity when the mouse cursor is on top of the DIV... but

Q#1 HOW CAN I ANIMATE ITS ZOOM ? like in the first example.

Q#2 (the most important) HOW CAN I LINK...A CHECKBOX STATE WITH A SPECIFIC DIV? I mean, how can I show a specific div depending on what a checkbox is selected (or several)? What should I use: if else construction... or switch - case? Or something else ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "zoom"? CSS zoom?

Comment: If you click this link http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/ and  then click the blue btn in the sidebar, you will see the modal window. There will be a list of logos that zoom in a little when you hower it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Twitter Bootstrap: [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

It's easy to use and save you from lots of work.

example as in: http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/

you could use jquery, suppose the images are:

```
<img src=".." id="img1" style="display: none;"/>
<img src=".." id="img2" style="display: none;"/>
```

Now the checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="img1">
```

Now jquery:

```
$('input["checkbox"]').is(":checked"){
   var img = $(this).attr("class");
   $("#" + img).css("display","block");  //do your own stuff such as zoom..etc.. as you were saying

  // add for uncheck, to hide the picture etc...
  }
```

Comment: thanks for this, but I also need to understand how to LINK a state of checkbox with animating of a specific div